# How to create an endpoint in loopback to create endpoints at runtime without need to restart the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I am working on creating an application which is very dynamic in nature and needs to create API on the fly. I have decided to use loopback as my backend, I want to create an API by just passing the model as json it create an endpoint and have the functionality of crud operation on the fly. Is there a way to do this in loopback? Or can someone guide me in the right direction? I have checked the StackOverflow other questions in this regard but they are not guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here the documentation for it.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-models.html

Comment: i have read that already, but it is not what i am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/72d48c3bfa478ec0d05b2b168bbab321f4423918/example/colors/app.js) example from the loopback source

```
var schema = {
  name: String,
};

app.dataSource('db', {connector: 'memory'});
var Color = app.registry.createModel('color', schema);
app.model(Color, {dataSource: 'db'});
```

Comment: Thanks, it is looking promising.